Laravel Octane Dispatch Job goes no where
I just switched over to Laravel Octane in production and the only thing I have noticed which doesn't appear to be working is dispatching jobs. I have this line:
return dispatch(new GenerateReport($record, auth()->user()));

This works as expected if I switch the server back to php-fpm, but when I am using octane nothing happens.
Here is the snippet from that job as well
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Filament\Notifications\Actions\Action;
use Filament\Notifications\Notification;


class GenerateReport implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


Which version of PHP and laravel you are using?Laravel Octane requires PHP 8.1+.

I am running laravel 10.10 and php 8.3.11 so it should be supported for octane

i have updated to the latest version of Laravel and Octane and I still see this issue persisting. This is being called from Filament panel, would that make a difference?
